# Finding the maximum value of $\sin\left((2^n)^\circ\right)$ where $n \in \Bbb N$

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic

Found this question in my math textbook where it asked us to find $\max\sin\left((2^n)^\circ\right)$ where $n \in \Bbb N$ and $2^n$ expressed in god forbid degrees.
It's in the arithmetic section but the problem seems analytic at first.
I tried finding if $n$ exists such that $2^n=90+360k$ for some $k\in \Bbb N$ but I can't quite get some progress with it, then I tried using functions where I minimize the difference between $2^n-90-360k$ to get close to the max of the $\sin$ function that we all know is $1$ but not luck there either.
Any help would be appreciated!
PS: I know how to study functions using basic calculus, I just graduated high school. I wouldn't mind a little advanced math to explore and learn.
EDIT : just found out that $\sin(2^{96})=0.99..\gt \sin(2^6)$ which contradicts Ben's answer, maybe $2^n\mod360$ isn't periodic ?

Comment: oh Im sorry I should add that I just graduated high school

Comment: If you know modular arithmetic, reducing mod 3 you can see that $2^=90+360$ does not hold for any pair of integers n, k

Comment: and if degrees bother you so much you can always switch to radians by multiplying by $180/\pi$

Comment: Oh yeah I just figured that $1$ is impossible but then comes the question of finding a closer value to $90$ , for the degrees thing I think the question made it that way to find it easier ? since switching to radians we don't work in arithmetic anymore.

Comment: For radians you can get as close to 1 as you like but never reach it.  For degrees you want to consider powers of 2 modulo 360: can you do better than $\sin(128^\circ)$? what about $\sin(524288^\circ)$?

Answer (score 6):

Credit to Henry for the inspiration on this solution.

I started by listing out the sequence generated by $2^n$ mod $360$: $2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 152, 304, 248, 136, 272, 184, 8...$ The sequence produced by taking the sine of each term of this sequence is equal to the sequence produced by taking the sine of each term of the raw $2^n$ sequence, because subtracting (or adding) multiples of $360$ from the input of a sine function doesn't change its output.

As you can see, the sequence repeats itself (eventually looping back to 8). Therefore, there are finitely many values of $sin(2^n)$, and you can easily work out the maximum.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer! I assume the max would be the one closer to 90 which is 64 right ?